# refresh em pagina

Tags: php

Bom dia!
gostaria da ajuda de voces , pois estou precisando dar refresh em um pagina  em um determinado horario , consegui esse script ,porem nao esta funcionando. Se puderem me ajudar agradeço .

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function atualizaPagina(){
      momentoAtual = new Date();
      hora = momentoAtual.getHours();
      minuto = momentoAtual.getMinutes();
     segundo = momentoAtual.getSeconds();

horaAtual = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;

if(horaAtual=='3:04:0') window.location.href='painel_unidade_1.php';
if(horaAtual=='12:0:0') window.location.href='painel_unidade_5.php';
setTimeout("atualizaPagina()",1000);
}
atualizaPagina();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função / método `setTimeout` deve ser utilizada das seguinte maneira:

```
setTimeout(função, tempo);
```

Não ira funcionar se utilizado desses jeitos:

```
// Não funciona
setTimeout("atualizaPagina()", 1000);
// Também não funciona
setTimeout(atualizaPagina(), 1000);
```

Jeitos correto de utilizar:

```
// Funciona
setTimeout(function() { atualizaPagina(); }, 1000);
// Também funciona
setTimeout(atualizaPagina, 1000);
```

## Exemplo funcionando.

```js
function atualizaPagina(){
  momentoAtual = new Date();
  hora = momentoAtual.getHours();
  minuto = momentoAtual.getMinutes();
  segundo = momentoAtual.getSeconds();

  horaAtual = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
  console.log(horaAtual);
  if(horaAtual=="3:41:0"){
    window.location.href='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234462/refresh-em-pagina';
  }
  if(horaAtual=='4:0:0') {
    window.location.href='https://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
  }
  console.log("ATUALIZANDO ...");
  setTimeout(atualizaPagina, 1000);
}
atualizaPagina();
```

## Exemplo extra

Vamos supor que você precise dar refresh na página de uma em uma hora, já imaginou ter que colocar linhas e linhas de condições para poder verificar o horário certo para cada página ? Daria um certo trabalho também para manutenção.

Pensando nisso, podemos simplificar todo esse processo criando um `objeto`, veja abaixo um exemplo.:

```
// Apenas para exemplo.
// Criamos o objeto RefreshAgenda, e adicionamos as propriedades ( Horários e Páginas ).
// Você pode adicionar quantos quiser, seguindo a mesma estrutura.
var RefreshAgenda = {
  '5:22:0': 'http://uol.com.br',
  '6:28:0': 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
};
```

E dentro da função `atualizaPagina()` crie apenas uma condição que verifica se no objeto `RefreshAgenda` contém o índice com o valor da variável `horaAtual`, caso tiver ele faz o refresh.

```
// Verifica se objeto RefreshAgenda contém o índice horaAtual
if(RefreshAgenda[horaAtual]){
  console.log(horaAtual + " Redirecionando para.: " + RefreshAgenda[horaAtual]);
  window.location.href= RefreshAgenda[horaAtual];
}
```

```js
// Apenas para exemplo.
// Criamos o objeto RefreshAgenda, e adicionamos as propriedades ( Horários e Páginas ).
// Você pode adicionar quantos quiser, seguindo a mesma estrutura.
var RefreshAgenda = {
  '4:50:0': 'http://uol.com.br',
  '5:50:0': 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
};

function atualizaPagina(){
  momentoAtual = new Date();
  hora = momentoAtual.getHours();
  minuto = momentoAtual.getMinutes();
  segundo = momentoAtual.getSeconds();

  horaAtual = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo;
  // Verifica se objeto RefreshAgenda contém o índice horaAtual
  if(RefreshAgenda[horaAtual]){
    console.log(horaAtual + " Redirecionando para.: " + RefreshAgenda[horaAtual]);
    window.location.href= RefreshAgenda[horaAtual];
  }
  setTimeout(atualizaPagina, 1000);
}
atualizaPagina();
```

Comment: perfeito sou muito grato a vcs...obrigado mesmo